# PrestaShop - Create an "add to cart' button for a product on checkout

Tags: prestashop, product

Is there a way to create an "add to cart" button for a specific product of my catalog, in the checkout process ? For example on the shipping or payment page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In PS 1.6 you can achieve it with a simple link like this:

`http://your-shop.com/cart?add=1&id_product=1&ipa=1&token=ea77f7d7169d5044638643fe4fcd2c99`

Where...

- `id_product` is the product id you want to add
- `ipa` is the attribute id of the product
- `token` is the static token

Inside a smarty file you can generate a link with this code:

`{$link->getPageLink('cart', true, NULL, 'add=1&id_product=1&ipa=1&token='|cat:$static_token, false)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}`